# Passing drop down value through link in JSP

Tags: jsp

I am not able to pass the drop down value through link in JSP page .

Here is code

```
  <select name="dropdown" id="month">
    <option value="JAN">JAN</option>
    <option value="FEB">FEB</option>
    <option value="MAR">MAR</option>
    <option value="APR">APR</option>
    <option value="MAY">MAY</option>
    <option value="JUN">JUN</option>
    <option value="JUL">JULY</option>
    <option value="AUG">AUG</option>
    <option value="SEP">SEP</option>
    <option value="OCT">OCT</option>
    <option value="NOV">NOV</option>
    <option value="DEC">DEC</option>
 </select> 



<a href="<%=application.getContextPath() %>/viewtrans?requestType=viewTrans&custId=<%=custId%>">View</a>
```

Now how should I pass the dropdown value through the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its same as you done for others if it is a string,

```
<a href="<%=application.getContextPath() %>/viewtrans?requestType=viewTrans&custId=<%=custId%>&optionVal=<%=dropdown%>">View</a>
```

**If you need to send multiple values , you have to pass it through the array**

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Can you post the full error message you are getting?

Comment: <h4>Click View for your Transactions...</h4> <select name="dropdown" id="month"> <option value="JAN">JAN</option> <option value="FEB">FEB</option> <option value="MAR">MAR</option> <option value="APR">APR</option> <option value="MAY">MAY</option> <option value="JUN">JUN</option> <option value="JUL">JULY</option> <option value="AUG">AUG</option> <option value="SEP">SEP</option> <option value="OCT">OCT</option> <option value="NOV">NOV</option> <option value="DEC">DEC</option> </select>                             this is drop down..

Comment: Here is link .. -----here im getting error as drop down coundnt be resolved.
    <a href="<%=application.getContextPath() %>/viewtrans?requestType=viewTrans&custId=<%=custId%>&month=<%=dropdown%>">View</a>

Comment: Can you post the jsp or servlet where you are retrieving this values? please just edit your question dont post it as comment