# Passing dropdown value from Jsp

Tags: java, jsp, drop-down-menu, jstl

I have gone through [Passing drop down value through link in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22781525/passing-drop-down-value-through-link-in-jsp), but still I am unable to pass dropdown value

```
<select name="statuses">
                    <option value="1">On hold</option>
                    <option value="2">Confirmed</option>
                    <option value="3">Declined</option>
                </select>
                <a href="<c:url value="/tickets">
                   <c:param name="action" value="changestatus" />
                   <c:param name="ticketId" value="${entry.key}" />
                   <c:param name="optVal" value="${statuses}" /></c:url>" >Change</a>
```

But when I click on `Change` the url seems to be like this

```
http://localhost:8080/customer-support/tickets?action=changestatus&ticketId=1&optVal=
```

As you can see that `optVal` value is empty. How can I send selected dropdown value to url?

Answer (score 0):

You are mix client-side and server-side logic together.

1. The server evalute the jsp (tags,el,..) and create an html page from it.
2. The html is sent to the Browser, where the user can select or input information.
3. When a form is submitted by the browser, the values of the form fields such as select,input,textarea,.. are send back to the server
4. Then the server can evaluate the information.

This what you do in `<c:url` with `${statuses}` happens on the server. The User has not be involved jet. The value of `${statuses}` is something you have prepared as attribute. It is not the parameter from user.

You can achieve such link creation on the client side with a form and hidden input fields:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="get">
              <select name="optVal">
                    <option value="1">On hold</option>
                    <option value="2">Confirmed</option>
                    <option value="3">Declined</option>
                </select>
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="changestatus">
                <input type="hidden" name="ticketId" value="${entry.key}">
                <input type="submit" value="Change">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

You add each parameter that should not changeable by user in an input hidden field.

Comment: Yeah that is other way around. This can also implement using javascript, but I just wanted to know if there is simple solution (like as in question) exists.